# C# Server Socket stops accepting new connections

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpserver, raw-sockets

I’ve written TCP socket catcher based on server socket and events for transferring caught connections to high level.

```
public class TcpCatcher
{
    private static readonly Exception IsStartedException = new Exception("Catcher has already been started.");

    private int _port;
    private int _openTimeout;

    private Socket _serverSocket;
    private SocketAsyncEventArgs _acceptAsyncArg;


    public int Port
    {
        get => _port;
        set
        {
            if (IsStarted)
                throw IsStartedException;
            _port = value;
        }
    }

    public int OpenTimeout
    {
        get => _openTimeout;
        set
        {
            if (IsStarted)
                throw IsStartedException;
            _openTimeout = value;
        }
    }

    public bool IsStarted { get; protected set; }

    public event Action<Socket> ConnectionCatched;
    public event Action<string> Log;

    public TcpCatcher()
    {
        _acceptAsyncArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        _acceptAsyncArg.SetBuffer(null, 0, 0);
        _acceptAsyncArg.Completed += OnAcceptSocket;
    }

    private void OnLog(string message)
    {
        if (Log != null)
            Log(message);
    }

    private void AcceptSocket()
    {
        OnLog("AcceptSocket is executing");
        bool isAsync;

        do
        {
            isAsync = _serverSocket.AcceptAsync(_acceptAsyncArg);

            if (!isAsync)
            {
                OnLog($"AcceptAsync finished Sync.");
                if (_acceptAsyncArg.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
                    ConnectionCatched(_acceptAsyncArg.AcceptSocket);
            }
        } while (!isAsync);
        OnLog("AcceptSocket finished");
    }

    private void OnAcceptSocket(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs asyncArg)
    {
        OnLog("Caught new socket!");

        if (asyncArg.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
        {
            OnLog($"Socket has bad status:${asyncArg.SocketError}");
            asyncArg.AcceptSocket?.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectionCatched(asyncArg.AcceptSocket);
        }

        OnLog($"Caught socket was processed");
        asyncArg.AcceptSocket = null;

        if (IsStarted)
            AcceptSocket();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        OnLog($"Starting");
        IsStarted = true;
        _serverSocket?.Close();
        _serverSocket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Port));
        _serverSocket.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);
        AcceptSocket();

    }

    public void Finish()
    {
        OnLog($"Stopping");
        _serverSocket.Disconnect(false);
        _serverSocket.Close();
        _serverSocket.Dispose();
        _serverSocket = null;
        IsStarted = false;
    }
}
```

Catchers are used in a Windows Service and initialized when the service is started. They work about 2-4 days and stop for unknown reasons accepting sockets one by one. Can you explain why it may be and how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Your only error handling is cleaning up (`if (asyncArg.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
            asyncArg.AcceptSocket?.Close();`). This means you will not find out about errors. You could add an error event, relay all errors and log them somewhere.

Comment: Looks very similar to posting yesterday (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50554018/socket-server-listening-all-the-time#comment88123994_50554018).  Usually the way to start is to check status using cmd.exe > Netstat -a.  It will tell if the connection was closed properly or improperly or is still listening.

Comment: @usr, Logging is used in this part of code. I didn't show it in the code block, because loggin in my opinion isn't relate to common catcher work. Of course, if it is nessesary, I will change code. But in any cases, log files have already been checked, there were no exceptions.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, try it. It may be very useful.

Comment: Post the logging code. It might be faulty and miss errors.

Comment: @usr, ready. Changed code block.

Comment: OK, thx. Looks fine which is bad news I guess because I now have no contribution to make :)